# Domain name resolution problem when starting yarn in HDP

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I have installed HDP2.7.5. but When I start the yarn & hdfs Service.I have encountered the following problems.

The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL:

```
http://n15hdp02:50070/webhdfs/v1/tmp?
Unable to determine IP address from host name n15hdp02
The DNS server returned:

Name Error: The domain name does not exist.

This means that the cache was not able to resolve the hostname presented in the URL. Check if the address is correct.

Your cache administrator is root.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgSYN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tys9Z.png)

Comment: Hadoop prefers that your DNS servers are already setup. It appears yours is not. Use IP addresses instead.

Comment: How can I disable DNS server？Only use IP addresses.

Comment: Well, it's preferred you fix or setup a DNS server. If you want to use IPs, edit your core-site.xml to set fs.defaultFS to use an IP for the error mentioned. Do the same in hdfs-site and yarn-site.xml for similar service addresses